# Using C# MVC: EditorFor is not working on a nested list of models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, http-post, editorfor

I just started using MVC and C# and have ran into a problem with my web application. I am passing a list of models into the view. In each model, is a list of objects that I want to edit. However, after I hit the submit button as a POST request the list of objects that were initially passed through as a GET (successfully) have become empty. How can I get the MVC form to pass the list of models and the list of objects in the models back into the controller with the data that has edited.

View Model

```
public class TeacherViewModel
string TeacherName {get; set;}
List<Student> StudentList {get; set;}
string ClassName {get; set;}
```

Object

```
public partial class Student
int StudentID {get; set;}
string StudentName {get; set;}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public action edit(List<TeacherViewModel> tvmList)
if (vtmList == null)
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
try{
foreach (tvm in tvmList)
{
foreach (student in tvm.students)
{
if (studentHasChanged)
editStudent(student)
}
}
return RedirectToAction("index", "class");
}
```

View

```
@model List<TeacherViewModel>

@using (@html.beginform("edit", "class", FormMethod.Post))
{
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
<tr>
<td>
@html.displayfor(modelItem => modelItem[i].TeacherName)
@html.hiddenfor(modelItem => modelItem[i].TeacherName)
</td>
<td>
@html.displayfor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ClassName)
@html.hiddenfor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ClassName)
</td>
<td>
@for (int z = 0; z < Model[i].Students.count(); z++)
{
if (Model[i].Students[z].StudentID == 1)
{
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Students[z].StudentName) <-- This is the line I'm having trouble with
}
}
</td>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

How does the hidden input and editorfor work when submitted through the httpPost request? And what am I doing incorrectly that prevents me from getting a list of "students" back with the populated results (edited, or original data)?

Comment: When you debug, `modelItem => modelItem[i].Students[z].StudentName` posts as null? Or rather the entire list of students? Also try `@Html.TextBoxFor`. I've had lots of bad experiences with `Html.EditorFor` posting null values

Comment: Search for EditorTemplates, define some and asp will do most of the work out of the box

Comment: Collection indexers need to start at zero and be consecutive by default. Your `if` clause means that is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: The post returns a list of view models but the view models do not contain a list.